# Should multi-threading be considered while using receiving data using Websocket

Tags: c#, json, websocket, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I have to read the data from WebSocket URL ( Full Web socket endpoint is provided. i.e. 'wss://someURL/ws/websocket' ). The response is json based on information. In fact, these are events of IOT devices.

**Example Response :**

```
{
  "device_id": "ce95003e-a619-4992-bc47-e4473816158d",
  "id": "dae69be5-8da0-459c-af2f-683ca0f7e4a1",
  "timestamp": "2016-03-15T19:35:16.500014Z",
  "status": "running"
}
```

The device statuses could be running, repaired, errored, and idle. If the device status is errored, it will be repaired automatically and a repaired event will be sent before resetting it to idle again.

I am using the following code as of now to connect with WebSocket for receiving data.

```
ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // storing data here, Could be Concurrent Queue ???

        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://someURL.io/ws/websocket"), CancellationToken.None);
        while (true)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

This data will be preserved later in the databases or in memory ( perhaps doesn't matter ). But the data needed to be exposed as JSON-based API for frontends to show.

Question: Do I need to handle multi-threading? In which context, data concurrent access must be implemented? Does the buffer need to be thread-safe ?

Answer (score 0):

You very rarely *need* multi threading.

Using async/await works perfectly well in a single threaded context (i.e. a UI program).

If you are running it in a multi threaded context, like a console program, it can be a little more difficult. But you should be fine as long as you are awaiting any tasks as soon as possible. That should prevent more than one thread from running at any point in time, at least for *your* code.

Your specific example looks perfectly fine to me.

If you *do* use multi threaded code, i.e. something like `Task.Run`, you *will* need to ensure that your code is thread safe.

Comment: More clarification: I am becoming a client of some specific Server from where a stream of events is accepted. 

But I think still need concurrency for reader/writer scenarios.

Comment: For example, I am listening and writing the data in a buffer. Machine with certain id bringing status as 'idle' and few seconds later 'running'.
If multiple readers of JSON api hit the REST api server, they should not get different results. Right ?

Comment: @Usman the webserver *should* handle concurrent requests just fine. If concurrent readers get the same result is up to the server, for all I know it could return random values. You do not *need* concurrency for reading/writing, just do one after each other at a time. Concurrency might improve things like performance/latency, but it may add a lot of complexity you need to deal with to ensure it is safe.